# Reiniciar contador si una acción no es completada en Arduino

Tags: arduino

En la escuela me piden un programa en Arduino que al mantener presionado un botón encienda un led. Al soltar el botón, que cuente 5 segundos y luego apague el led.

Pero si el botón es presionado por ejemplo al segundo 3, el contador regrese a 5 segundos como estado inicial.

Les dejo mi código (pero está mal):

```
const int buttonPin = 2;     
const int ledPin =  13;      

int buttonState = 0;         

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    if(buttonState==0) { 
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      delay(5000);
    } else {
      return loop();
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: por favor lee [ask], edita y coloca un título descriptivo, pues decir que *ayuda por favor* no aclara nada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta mal la programacion, los pasos a seguir serian los siguientes.

1. Obtener los estados de los componentes con lo que trabajaremos (led, boton).
2. Condicionar los datos obtenidos para realizar una lectura/escritura en los componentes (led).

Como puedes ver en tu código el primer paso te falto obtener el estado del botón. Tenido esos dos datos podemos ver que en caso de que el led este apagado y el botón presionado escribimos el estado del led en encendido, si ese caso no se diera, condicionaríamos, si el led esta encendido y el botón sin presionar esperar 5 segundos y luego escribiremos el estado del led en apagado. Quedando el código:

```c
    const int buttonPin = 2; 
    const int ledPin =  13; 
    int buttonState = LOW;  
    int ledState = LOW; 

    void setup(){
        pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
    }

    void loop() {
        buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
        ledState = digitalRead(ledPin);

        if(buttonState == HIGH && ledState == LOW){
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        } else {
            if(ledState == HIGH && buttonState == LOW){
                delay(5000);
                digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza [`PulseIn`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.PulseIn). Por ejemplo:

```
int tiempo = pulseIn(13,HIGH)
```

La variable `tiempo` almacenará los milisegundos en los que el pin 13 estaba en HIGH.